# Distribution of $X_t=\mathbb{E}(B_1\mathbb{I}_{|B_1|\geq1}-B_1\mathbb{I}_{|B_1|<1}|\mathcal{F}_t)$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, brownian-motion, martingales

I am asked to consider the process

$$X_t=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_t),\quad X=B_1\mathbb{I}_{|B_1|\geq1}-B_1\mathbb{I}_{|B_1|<1}=\begin{cases}B_1&\text{if }|B_1|\geq1\\-B_1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

for $t\in[0,1]$, where $\{B_t\}$ is a standard BM and $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(B_s:s\in[0,t])$. I am tasked to obtain the following:

i) Find the distribution of $X$ and $X_t$, and prove $X_t$ is a martingale;

ii) Show that $X_t=B_t-2f(B_t,\sqrt{1-t})$ where $f(x,s)=\mathbb{E}\left[(x+sZ)\mathbb{I}_{|x+sZ|<1}\right]$ and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and consequently derive a PDE with an initial condition based on $s$.

For i), the comments and current answer have explained why it is a martingale. I also now know that for ii), we have to use Ito’s formula and make the drift term disappear.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suppose that $\mathcal{F} = \{ \varnothing, \Omega \}$. Hence $X_t  = const$. Suppose that $\mathcal{F} $ is a sigma-algebra, generated by $X$. Hence $X_t$ is not $const$.  The problem i) is not correct: the distribution depends of filtration.

Comment: To your question: "why is $\{X_t, t \geq 0\}$ a martingale?". $X$ is an integrable random variable so $X_t:=E[X|\mathscr F_t]$ defines a UI-martingale.

Comment: @BotnakovN. after discussing with some of my coursemates we think the filtration is meant to be generated by the BM not by $X_t$, sorry about that!

Comment: @UBM hi, I understand $X_t$ satisfies the martingale property and integrability conditions, but I don’t see how it is even adapted to the filtration we have chosen for our space, isn’t that a necessary requirement for a martingale (or even a semimartingale)?

Comment: Note that $X_t:=E[X|\mathscr F_t], t \geq 0$ is $\{ \mathscr F_t \}-$adapted by definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: You usually post nice exercises, just courious, are these from a masters?

Comment: @UBM yes, these are from a revision pack for my computational finance master’s exams!

Comment: @user107224, is there any lecture notes or problems and solutions? They may help.

Comment: @BotnakovN. no, sadly; will read your answer in more careful detail in a bit!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but it may be a hint to further solution.

$X_t$ is Levy martingale hence it's martingale.

Put $\xi = B_t$ and $\eta = B_1 - B_t$.

Thus $X_t = E( B_1 - 2 B_1 I_{|B_1| < 1} | \mathcal{F}_t) = E(h(\xi, 
\eta) | \mathcal{F}_t) $
where $h(a,b) = a + b- 2(a +b) I_{|a + b| < 1}$.

We know that $\xi$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. As $\eta$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$ are independent we have

$$X_t = E(h(\xi, \eta) | \mathcal{F}_t) = g(\xi),$$
where $g(x) =  E(h(\xi, \eta) | \xi = x)$.

Further, $g(x) =  E(h(\xi, \eta) | \xi = x) =  E(h(x, \eta) | \xi = x) = Eh(x, \eta) $ by independence. Put $\eta = \sqrt{1-t} \zeta$. As $\eta \sim N(0, 1-t)$ we have $\zeta \sim N(0,1)$. Thus
$$g(x) = Eh(x, \eta) = E( x + \eta- 2(x +\eta) I_{|x + \eta| < 1} )= x - 2E(x +\eta) I_{|x + \eta| < 1} $$
$$= x -  2E(x +\sqrt{1-t} \zeta) I_{|x +\sqrt{1-t} \zeta| < 1} = x - 2f(x, \sqrt{1-t})$$
and
$$X_t = g(\xi) =  \xi - 2f(\xi, \sqrt{1-t}) = B_t - 2f(B_t, \sqrt{1-t}) .$$

We proved that $X_t = H(B_t, t)$. Now we may try to find the distribution of $X_t$ or use Ito formula, but a function $f(x,s)$ doesn't look good.